# Installing Ubuntu on separate SSD on a FreeDOS laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

I bought a new Lenovo 330 with SSD + HDD. FreeDOS is installed on the HDD. 
Now I need to install Ubuntu (or Linux Mint) on the SSD, but be able to keep FreeDOS functioning and, if necessary, later erase Ubuntu.

Installing on SSD is easy, I just choose "Something Else" and then the SSD, since FreeDOS is on the HDD. But how can I make sure about what exactly happens after I restart the system? Will there be a fool-proof simple dual-boot choice?

When I begin the installation, the installer warns me that my machine is using UEFI and if I "force" UEFI or something there could be trouble with the other OS...

(BTW, from within the LiveCD file manager I can't see the SSD drive or the HDD drive, just a 4GB File System. Normally, from Ubuntu I get to see both drives?)

Comment: Your FreeDos will be BIOS boot from MBR drive. But your hardware is UEFI and UEFI normally uses gpt partitioning. And UEFI & BIOS or not compatible, so you cannot dual boot from grub. But can dual boot from UEFI boot menu. Have you updated UEFI from lenovo and updated firmware for SSD? Those are main reasons drives not seen. Could be other settings in UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to try Ubuntu, you don't need to install it on your PC. You can use a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu.

You can find here the instruction on [how to make a bootable Ubuntu USB stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) if you don't have one already.

Hope it helps.
Cheers,
Peter

Comment: Sorry, i need to actually install Ubuntu. If not, I can't install the latest kernel and the laptop won't work properly with the kernel on the LiveCD. If I install the new kernel while using the LiveCD, I cant reboot to activate the kernel, so I'm stuck with the older one... and with an unusable computer. That's Lenovo...

Comment: You can run the USB stick and run Ubuntu as if was installed. Everything will work from the USB.

Comment: I know that, but I don't see how could I replace the Linux 14.5 kernel that doesn't work properly on Lenovo. I need at least 14.7.4 it seems.

Comment: Can you install Ubuntu on another pc(on usb or ssd) and update kernel? Or may be you can boot in recovery mode? and update kernel?

Comment: I finally installed Linux on the SSD from the LiveCD, but as expected, upon restart the laptop booted in FreeDOS/HDD. It seems that using a computer with HDD+SSD is particularly difficult. I've had a dual-boot Windows-Ubuntu computer with two partitions on a single HDD, but it was much simpler.